# Can't change html attribute via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video

This is very odd, I'm getting videos via `document.getElementsByTag('video')` and I can't change their width nor any other value.

Here's the Javascript code I'm using -

> window.onload = function() {
>
> ```
>             this.videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
>
>             var self = this;
>             for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
>                 videos.item(i).addEventListener("loadedmetadata", 
>                     (function(index){
>                         return function() {
>                             console.log(self.videos[index].offsetWidth); //shows X
>                             self.videos[index].offsetWidth = "480";
>                             console.log(self.videos[index].offsetWidth); //shows X
>                         }
>                     })(i)
>                 );
>             }
>         }
> ```

Example `<video>` tag -

```
<video><source src="videos/video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

I have no idea what it is happening and I've never encountered such kind of problem.
Thanks

EDIT:
 Using the setAttribute function just adds it to the live html, but the size isn't really changing

Comment: offsetWidth is a read-only *property* of an HTMLElement. Also, don't mistake HTML *attributes* and DOM *properties*.

Comment: @Sacho I've heared about these fellows, what can I do about it?
I've tried switching to byClass but same result..

Comment: How about the other values you can't change? What are they?

Comment: @Teemu I've tried accessing other width & height properties, 100% of them were read-only

Comment: Any help of these: [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), [`HTMLVideoElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement)?

Comment: doesn't console show any errors?

Comment: No errors.  
Well, I feel a bit a shamed but turns out that the `width` attribute of HTLMVideoElement solved it.
@Teemu Thanks for the solution. You want to add it so I'll mark it?

Comment: @Yehonatan I'd rather not, there seems to be correct answers for you already, just pick the best : ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `offsetWidth` is a read-only DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth) so you can not update it. However why not change the  element `width`?

```
window.onload = function() {
  this.videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
  var self = this;
  for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
    videos.item(i).addEventListener("loadedmetadata", 
      (function(index){
        return function() {
        self.videos[index].width = "480";
      }
    })(i));
  }
}
```

You can take into account the borders, paddings, margins...

Answer (score 1):

Note there is a difference between three things you are conflating into one:

- HTML *attributes*
- DOM *properties*
- CSS *styles*

This is an HTML *attribute*:
`<a href="http://example.com"></a>`

If you have a DOM element representing an HTML tag, you can modify the attributes like so:

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.setAttribute('href', "http://example.com")
```

This is a DOM *property*:

```
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = "http://example.com"
```

Note how a DOM *property* can be similarly named to an HTML *attribute*, but they are not the same thing. Oftentimes, changing an HTML *attribute* will modify the corresponding DOM *property*, but not vice versa. Also, not all attributes have matching properties, and so on.

CSS *styles* are accessed via the DOM *property* style(which corresponds to the HTML *attribute* style, but while the HTML *attribute* style is a string, the DOM *property* is an object):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.style.width = "500px";
a.style.height = "20%";
```

There are HTML *attributes* "width" and "height", but their use is deprecated in favor of using styles. Also, "width" and "height" as HTML attributes can only be numerical values representing pixels - while a CSS style can be many variations(pixels, ems, percentages, etc)

In your specific case, just modify the width styling of your element to change its width.

Another thing in your code is the usage of `this` and `self`, which is entirely unneeded. `this.videos` is setting a property on the global object(window) for no reason. You can also avoid closing over the index property by using .bind():

```
window.onload = function() {
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length;i++) {
        var video = videos.item(i);
        video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", (function () {
            console.log(this.offsetWidth);
            this.style.width = "480px";
            console.log(this.offsetWidth);
        }).bind(video));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and well explained answer but it has no clear solution to my problem. I really appreciate your answer and it is well written but I've picked @tmarwen's answer. Hope you'll understand.

Comment: I don't mind - I was just editing it to add a solution, since I noticed you were using `this` erroneously as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getAttribute and setAttribute, as in `videos[index].setAttribute('offsetWidth', 480)`

Comment: Haven't worked.. 
`self.videos[index].setAttribute('offsetWidth',480);`                                `console.log(self.videos[index].offsetWidth);`
Outputed 576

Comment: Oh, well, it did added the offesetWidth to the html but it haven't really changed the width of the video

Answer (score 0):

First off, this doesn't seem right:

```
for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++) {
```

Shouldn't it be `self.videos`? Fix that.

Then, to change the video size, you can change the size of the element:

```
self.videos[index].width = "480";
```

or, even better, the CSS width:

```
self.videos[index].style.width = "480px";
```

The size of the video itself will automatically extend to the size of the video element.

Comment: Thanks for the clear solution but it doesn't really matter if it self.video or videos in the loop. The scope is ok

Comment: You're welcome. You should still stick to one notation, because that function will fail in anything outside the window scope. And about the videos - try to use CSS for styling, rather than width/height HTML  attributes.